# What types of questions or answers should be made community wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, polling

I think it's about time that the community of SO/SF/SU decide what should and should not be community wiki.

In order to facilitate this, I recommend 1 suggestion per answer. Since this is community wiki, vote up/down based on whether you like or dislike the idea. If your idea only pertains to one site, please identify the site. And please do not post an answer duplicating what's already been posted - up-vote it (and maybe leave a comment...) instead!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5628

Comment: Why the downvote? That question does not attempt to define what should and should not be community wiki, while this one does. Unless I'm missing something, there is no definition of community wiki and I think the community should come up with one.

Answer (score 7):

Community Wiki posts should be for those that want to allow more people to edit the posts.

[Wiki FAQ mention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128742/how-does-editing-work-in-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 3):

A discussion

Answer (score 3):

A poll

Answer (score 3):

Questions for which useful **answers will involve lists of items**, such as
criteria or resources, because wiki mode will then allow these to be compiled into one answer rather than scattered over many.

Answer (score 2):

Questions that do not have a right answer.

There are discussions that are valuable to the community, such as [this one on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149778/is-software-engineering-dead) (since deleted). I think this is of interest to and benefits the community, however if there aren't right or wrong answers, no one should be able to gain reputation from posting, and therefore the question and all answers should be in community wiki.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes answers are edited into the question or mentioned in comments instead of being posted as a proper answer. Sometimes they are very old and the user who left it was "Last Seen" a long long time ago, with little incentive or likelihood for him to redeem the comment / edit. If you come upon these situations, moving them into your own answer is the way to go. If you expand them into a proper answer, it is sometimes fine; But if you want to move it into an answer without giving other users the negative impression that you want the rep from doing it, go Community Wiki!

Answer (score 0):

A question that is "Rep Whoring" (whatever that means)

Answer (score 0):

A subjective topic

Comment: Anything with the words, "Best" and "Must have" without a set of criteria to judge on definitely fits that bill.

Comment: I think this falls under http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7157/what-types-of-questions-or-answers-should-be-made-community-wiki/7158#7158 - truly subjective questions are those with no right or wrong answers.

Answer (score 0):

The only person to decide if a question is to be "wiki" is the asker, it should be completely up to her.

Answer (score -2):

A GTKY question (no real criteria for answers, just want to **g**et **t**o **k**now **y**ou...)

(These probably shouldn't be on SO at all, but a few can be fun and help users to see each other as people... and [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon) [will](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/programmer-jokes-whats-your-best-one) [never](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164432/what-real-life-bad-habits-has-programming-given-you) [die](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406760/whats-your-most-controversial-programming-opinion))

Comment: They do die. That question was deleted a couple of years ago.

Comment: And yet, somehow it's back.

Comment: It's magic! :-)

Answer (score -2):

Community Wiki answers do not incur reputation, so when your answer causes a negative reputation change, turn it into Community Wiki to regain your points.

Comment: Actually, the reputation changes *before* CW-fication are kept.

Comment: @Braiam Delete, edit to CW, undelete?