# If I don't want the points, can I make my answers "community wiki"?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is community wiki for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108136/what-is-community-wiki-for)

I get too many votes for weaker or viral answers and too few for hard worked ones. Can I make community wiki those answers that I do not want votes (therefore points) for?

Answer (score 10):

You could use CW in such cases, but bear in mind that it would make the answer editable also by users with a reputation of at least 100 (and not 2000 as the usual). This means that a user with a reputation of at least 100 points would be able to edit your answer without passing through a suggested edit that is then approved by another user.

Comment: I could check the modifications later on and if it is something I consider incorrect, roll it back.

Answer (score 10):

Why not take the points and put them to good use by placing a bounty on a hard question?

Comment: Because the votes will still be visible on answers where I do not want votes.