# Answer list only displays first 30 answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

The answer list only displays first 30 answers, for questions with lots of answers - no pagination or lazy-loading once you reach the bottom, to view the other answers.

Personally counted every answer twice.

Comment: You've been busy.  We appreciate it!  30 answers is a known limitation for answers at the moment but we will be upping that in a future release.

Comment: wow, **[30 answers ought to be enough for anybody](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171063/165773)** is implemented at last! :) Way to go SE team!

Comment: @gnat this is for the Android app, alpha version only.

Comment: @SamuelLiew do you see [meta-tag:status-planned]? I (want to) read this as: "Android is just a pilot version, we plan to spread it all over SE"

Comment: Btw, when you first load the question, it shows the correct number of answers on the answers tab, but then switches to 30  once the data is loaded.

Comment: This is probably related to this issue: [Android app cannot post answer in Formatting Sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196374/android-app-cannot-post-answer-in-formatting-sandbox)

Comment: @Geoff has the future arrived already? :-)

Comment: The Android app shows all answers now - **finally!** Thank you to whoever did this!