# Android app cannot post answer in Formatting Sandbox

Tags: bug, answers, markdown, android-app

I tried the [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) on the android app and I couldn't write an answer at all.

I will probably use [this sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194835/sandbox-for-android-app) to test for the android-app but not sure if you should be able to post an answer on that question. Is there some sort of answer limit that prevents people from posting answers on questions with lots of answers?

If necessary I can show a picture of where it cuts off on my phone.

Comment: Probably related: [Answer list only displays first 30 answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191524/answer-list-only-displays-first-30-answers)

Comment: Now that the app can list all answers, good luck *to scroll to the bottom* to add another answer ;-)