# How can I use stackexchange as notes repository?

Tags: discussion

I have tried mails to self and text files to keeping notes in one place, which I can reuse. However I have found them getting lost as time passes by. The "Anwser your own question" in stack exchange is good way of keeping notes to self. However if the question is simple e.g. "how to do something", stack exchange do not allow to post the question. I was wondering if there are guidelines to post simple questions with answer, which I and others can use.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The "Anwser your own question" in stack exchange is good way of keeping notes to self

No. It isn't. It is a good way to provide a good answer to a good question, if you have both.

> there are guidelines to post simple questions with answer, which I and others can use

Post a quality question. One that follows the guidelines - showing research, effort an so forth.

Post a quality answer. Again, one that follows our quality guidelines.

That's all there is to it.

---

If you are using the site for your personal note-taking, you are doing it wrong.

We want to have posts that help as many people as possible. Not just yourself.

Comment: Agree to both the points you raised. However I believe simple technical notes will be useful to others as well. I wanted to avoid morphing such item into a question.

Comment: @Manish - it is quite simple. If it isn't a question, it doesn't belong on a Stack Exchange site. If you can formulate it as a problem/solution pair, that's fine, if you can't - don't post it.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for bringing the clarity.

Comment: The title may be a duplicate, but the question itself differs completely in purpose.   I  saw references to community wikis where everyone could add input but have yet to find such things or a reference pointing to an answer in one.  If they do exist wouldn't that be better suited as a place to point someone to a well formed formal answer.   On The other hand if it's just strictly for personal notes then I would suggest using the Evernote app.

Comment: I guess I have seen community wikis they are just questions which have been converted to community comments, and I don't think that that would be a good idea to purposely create those as simulated questions and answers either.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108136/what-is-community-wiki-for